# How to align map entries

Tags: yaml-cpp

I wonder if there is a way to align the map lines so that the colons appear vertically?

I have tried SetIndent() and SetLocalIndent(), but with now visible effects.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Yaml-cpp writes its output as soon as it can, so it can't know if later on, you'll be using a very long key.